# Not able to get Azure Billing Account Id

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, billing, azure-billing-api, cost-management

I need to get Usage Details at Billing Account Scope for that firstly I used [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/2019-10-01-preview/billingaccounts/list) but It returns an empty value. I used the Bearer Access token for hitting this API.Is anything other than this am I missed?

[Postman Request attached as screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a17fU.png)

[image: Postman Request attached as screenshot]

Comment: It means you dont have access to those billing accounts

Comment: How to add access to that billing accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This api will return a value if account belongs to Modern billing

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're using the wrong API. To get Billing info you must provide billing account name:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/{billingAccountName}?api-version=2019-10-01-preview
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/2019-10-01-preview/billingaccounts/get

PS: you can use the "try it" and test if it will return the information you need.

You can also query usage API and use one of the available dimensions to get cost related info:

```
POST https://management.azure.com/{scope}/providers/Microsoft.CostManagement/query?api-version=2019-11-01
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/query/usage

Comment: Thank you, for using this api GET https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/{billingAccountName}?api-version=2019-10-01-preview I need Billing Account Name.

Comment: @DAK did you manage to find an answer? I am struggling with this also

Comment: No, not able get it.@isioutis that api requires billing account name

Comment: @DAK the API in the original question I mean , where it gets the list of billing accounts . 
I managed to get it to work but not on all my customers . Mostly I get empty list as you did .

Comment: log into your account and go to https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_GTM/ModernBillingMenuBlade/BillingAccounts

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I need to get the billing account list  from the API .

Comment: @isioutis to list you should use the following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/2019-10-01-preview/billingaccounts/list

Comment: @Thiago Custodio  That is the problem . The specific API call does not work as expected . 
It returns empty list ( while in portal I can actually see the billing accounts ) . 
There is no reference in documentation which permissions or how to setup so that this API call works correctly .

Comment: @isioutis you should create a service principal and grant this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/manage-billing-access#give-read-only-access-to-billing

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio this doc shows how to add permission on specific subscription . My problem starts higher . I need to get the billing account list so I can get the billing account id/name from API .